# Upgrading 2sxc that used Ghost Content Types to the Shared Global Content Types

Tags: 2sxc

We have a site that has several portals we used the Ghost Content Types on but now I see this was changed and we have upgraded 2sxc but now need to migrate I guess the method Ghost Content types once used. Is it just going and re-setting this up by exporting them and and adding as if it we were doing it for the first time or is their considerations since a lot of the content and current portals all leveraged the Ghost content types?

Basically asking if there is something we need to know to make this upgrade quick and easy and any issues since this used the Ghost content types before.

Tried updating a field to realize Ghost content types no longer work as they were removed on the upgrade of 2sxc from version 9.

Comment: Ghost types were not removed as far as I know. They have not had any new features but I believe they still work as they always did. 

Why do you think they have been removed?

Comment: It was just the ctrl - click that isn't needed and entering into debug mode to view them had changed which made it seem like something was off.